# Generate PDF with PRAWN using search results

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, pdf-generation, prawn

I have searched the other SO questions and it seems like there currently is not a question or sample that addresses the issue. If there is let me know and I will remove my question.ROR-4 PRAWN

I have basic implementation of PRAWN pdf generation on my site as noted below.

```
def booked_jobs
    @received_bookings = current_user.received_bookings.where(status:1).order(created_at: :asc).search(params)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.pdf do
        pdf = BookingPdf.new(@received_bookings, current_user)
        send_data pdf.render, filename: 'Bookings.pdf', type: 'application/pdf'
      end
    end
  end
```

`@received_bookings` is an ActiveRecord Relations array with booking objects.

When the page loads, I am able to download a PDF of all the bookings that pertain to my user. I run a search on the page using  self.search below.

```
def self.search(search)
  query = self.all
    if !search[:date_start].nil?
      attribs = columns.map(&:name)
      (search.keys & attribs).each do |search_field|
        search_value = search[search_field]
        unless search_value.empty?
          query = query.where("#{search_field} ILIKE ?", "%#{search_value}%")
        end
      end
      query = query.where(d_start:(search[:date_start]..search[:date_end]))
    end
   query
 end
```

After the search, I want the PDF that is generated to only include the results from the search itself. However the PDF is still generating all the bookings for that user.

My issue is I have no idea on what direction to go in. How can I make the pdf render with the updated `@received_bookings` information.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you need to pass the date range to your `booked_jobs` method as well and search based on same condition that was used in search page